# C++ Red de cubos mediante vectores

Tags: c++, array

Tengo este código que genera mil pasos, en cada paso se guardan: el **número de cubo** que es el número de paso, el paso es una combinación de **(i,j,k)**  el cual representa la coordenada asociada a ese paso.

Hasta ahora sólo he generado cada paso y sus respectivas coordenadas pero no sé cómo asociarlas para que por ejemplo.

**EDICION**

Con asociar me refiero a hallar la relación entre **coordendas** y **# de cubo**.

Si le doy coordenadas aleatorias al programa, ¿Cómo hago para qué mi código sepa qué # de cubo es? es decir, que por ejemplo el paso **#753** sea el cubo 753 con coordenadas **(i,j,k)** o viceversa, que yo escriba las coordenadas **(i,j,k)** y me diga qué **# de cubo** es. Para esto tal vez deba hallar una función que me guarde ambos datos, el # paso y las coordenadas, así al llamar a la función del n-ésimo paso, esta función tendrá las coordenadas de ese #.

```
 #include <iostream>    
 #include <cstdlib>     
 #include <ctime>       

 int main(){
 int x, y, z, n, Xmax, Xmin, Ymax, Ymin, Zmax, Zmin, Mx[1]={0}, My[1]={0}, Mz[1]={0};
 int cube[11][11][11]={0}, etiqueta;
    srand(time(NULL));

    n=10;
    etiqueta = 0;

    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++){
        for (int j=1; j<=n; j++){
            for (int k=1; k<=n; k++){

                Xmax = i + 1, Xmin = i;
                Ymax = j + 1, Ymin = j;             // 6 caras del cubo
                Zmax = k + 1, Zmin = k;

                if(i = Xmin) if(j = Ymin) if(k = Zmin)
                etiqueta++;                         // # "a" de cubo

                Mx[1] = i;
                My[1] = j;                          // coordenadas
                Mz[1] = k;
                cout << "\n\tCubo --- de --- Coordenadas";
                cout << "\n\t" << etiqueta << " ------------ (" << Mx[1] << ", " << My[1] << ", " <<                    Mz[1] << ")";     
                            }
                        } 
                    }   

                    cout << "\n\n\tEs una estructura de " << etiqueta << " cubos.\n" << endl;   

                    system("PAUSE");
                return 0;
                }
```

Comment: Y con esta, van 3 veces. Y aun no tengo claro lo que preguntas O_O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Tengo este código que genera mil pasos [...]

Tu ecosistema de cubos está compuesto de 11<sup>3</sup> o sea 1331 cubos:

```
int cube[11][11][11]={0}
```

Así que empezamos mal.

> Con asociar me refiero a hallar la relación entre **coordendas** y **# de cubo**.

Para saber ambos datos, es necesario conocer el tamaño de la colección de cubos en todos los ejes, ya que el índice y las coordenadas dependen de ello, tomemos por ejemplo 10 planos que podemos distribuir en 2×5 o 5×2:

```
+-+-+
|0|1|
+-+-+
|2|3|
+-+-+
|4|5|
+-+-+
|6|7|
+-+-+
|8|9|
+-+-+

+-+-+-+-+-+
|0|1|2|3|4|
+-+-+-+-+-+
|5|6|7|8|9|
+-+-+-+-+-+
```

Siendo exactamente el mismo número de planos, en la primera distribución el plano 6 está en la posición **(0,3)** mientras que en la segunda está en la posición **(1,1)**; por lo tanto cualquier cálculo que pretenda pasar de índice a coordenadas o de coordenadas a índice, debe tener en cuenta el tamaño de la colección de elementos en cada uno de los ejes; estas funciones te lo calculan:

```
struct punto { unsigned x{}, y{}, z{}; };

template <unsigned ALTO, unsigned ANCHO, unsigned LARGO>
punto indice_a_coordenada(unsigned indice)
{
    unsigned x = indice % ANCHO;
    unsigned y = indice / (ANCHO * ALTO);
    unsigned z = (indice / ANCHO) % ALTO;
    return {x, y, z};
}

template <unsigned ALTO, unsigned ANCHO, unsigned LARGO>
unsigned coordenada_a_indice(const punto &coordenada)
{
    return {(ANCHO * coordenada.z) + (ANCHO * ALTO * coordenada.y) + coordenada.x};
}
```

Puedes usarlo así:

```
int main()
{
    std::random_device dispositivo;
    std::mt19937 generador(dispositivo());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned> distribucion_coordenada(0, 9),
                                            distribucion_indice(0, 999);

    punto p{ distribucion_coordenada(generador),
         distribucion_coordenada(generador),
         distribucion_coordenada(generador) };

    int i = distribucion_indice(generador);

    std::cout << "El cubo en la coordenada " << p << " tiene el indice: "
          << coordenada_a_indice<10, 10, 10>(p) << '\n'
          << "El cubo en indice " << i << " tiene la coordenada: "
          << indice_a_coordenada<10, 10, 10>(i);

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVNNi9swED1bv2LY0o3UuttdeiiO00AopT0sXSg9LgSvpAaBLQlZXpIY//ZUH44/luypPSRm5j1m3jzNUK0/7Cg9nd4IScuGcVgJVVvDi2qNxpwpJFMugxzUUAu6kVZBC42sxU5yBvu2S@Hg/45tl0OXeypbLvtacK00N4VVBlYr/AJJgSpZn4tea4JalBhuGyNBOT4s8MJ/9M3ef65SuIrhYR4eA5csctQhZHmly8I67YPGzf3vh3SUvPn59cc0vt/8@v6wRlGFkExQvi22VCnDuCxYgQdmBIPM0QD40ufhbSydT9DDiH4EHGB4FwSRKe3oaHjgBRrx5RwvHyxp985p53P3b3MO8TihGzc2x7MHGQnTl2mHMUb85kjg/Xy@OX7w@CTexyGEtFAVQuLQIKxH3Lgt48/eDCZqrWphxbPKe0Jl77Ls02fYcek2iymDJyRMyJnXSPFHmcpNZreOYY14aqxQcvBrDec0denpg9@mkJF0DvcGeSjLXBNASbRJt6@VGRSSFCXJ/2L5E0u8ccItzSWJI9UzgxdUNTbczLcSaPOkgEsoi8mD9KcUOGCFqwC87Dd3GcEL67K6c3bE3xprEs7wUS7cGC969asd6ohpk5mIvtGFE5w1EmGufhtv3R6dTn8B)</kbd>.