# red de cubos 3D en C++

Tags: c++, base-de-datos, matrices, float

Este código genera una estructura de mil cubos ubicados por sus coordenadas, busca cualquier cubo dentro de la estructura y da sus coordenadas, el problema es que solo trabaja con coordenadas enteras y fallan los resultados un poco, necesito buscar los cubos usando coordenadas decimales, pensaba en definir cada sub intervalo entre **i** e **i+1** y buscar números de coma flotante dentro de intervalos enteros pero no me da lo que espero

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

 using namespace std;    

int buscarCubo(int c1[1001], int c2[1001], int c3[1001], int c[1001]){
int x=0, y=0, z=0;

cout << "\n\tIngresa la coordenada x: ", cin >> x; 
cout << "\n\tIngresa la coordenada y: ", cin >> y; 
cout << "\n\tIngresa la coordenada z: ", cin >> z; 

 for(int i=1; i<=1000; i++){
   if(c1[i]==x && c2[i]==y && c3[i]==z ){
    return c[i];
   }
 }
return -1;
}


int main(){  
int coord1[1001], coord2[1001], coord3[1001], cubo[1001], Mx[1], My[1], Mz[1], res=0, salir=0, tec=0;    
int n, Xmax, Xmin, Ymax, Ymin, Zmax, Zmin, etiqueta;

n=10;
etiqueta = 0;
cout << "\n\tPrograma que simula una geometria construida por cubos,";
cout << "\n\tcada uno de los cuales esta ubicado por sus coordenadas (x,y,z)" << endl;

for (int i=1; i<=n; i++){
    for (int j=1; j<=n; j++){
        for (int k=1; k<=n; k++){

            Xmax = i + 1, Xmin = i;
            Ymax = j + 1, Ymin = j;             // límites (caras)
            Zmax = k + 1, Zmin = k;

            if(i = Xmin) if(j = Ymin) if(k = Zmin)
            etiqueta++;                         

            Mx[1] = i;
            My[1] = j;                          // coord aux (paso)
            Mz[1] = k;

            coord1[etiqueta]=Mx[1];
            coord2[etiqueta]=My[1];
            coord3[etiqueta]=Mz[1];             // coordenadas

            cubo[etiqueta]=etiqueta;
        }
    } 
}


cout << "\n\n\t";
system("PAUSE");
cout << "\n\n\tBusca un cubo:" << endl; 
res=buscarCubo(coord1,coord2,coord3,cubo);

if(res != -1){
    cout << "\n\n\tEn esas coordenadas esta el cubo #: " << res << ".\n" << endl;   
}else{
    cout << "\n\n\tCubo no encontrado " << endl; 
}

return 0;
}
```

Lo siguiente es una opción para resolver mi problema pero no me queda, ayuda por favor, ya es mas fácil para alguien con mas experiencia que la de un iniciado en programación.

```
int buscarCubo(float c1[1001], float c2[1001], float c3[1001], float c[1001]){
float x=0.0, y=0.0, z=0.0;
int Xmax, Xmin;

cout << "\n\tIngresa la coordenada x: ", cin >> x; 
cout << "\n\tIngresa la coordenada y: ", cin >> y; 
cout << "\n\tIngresa la coordenada z: ", cin >> z; 

for(int i=1; i<=1000; i++){

    if(x >= i && x < i+1){  
     if(y >= i && y < i+1){
      if(z >= i && z < i+1){
      //if(c1[i]==x && c2[i]==y && c3[i]==z ){
       return c[i];
       }}}
    return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Es necesario crear una formación de 1001 elementos si solo vas a usar 1000?, la indexación en C++ es basada en cero, es decir, tu primer elemento tendrá índice 0, en todos los bloques `for` empiezas por 1, no se si esto es necesario o no estas teniendo en cuenta lo anterior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Este código genera una estructura de mil cubos ubicados por sus coordenadas, busca cualquier cubo dentro de la estructura y da sus coordenadas.

Empezamos mal. No tienes mil cubos si no 4004 enteros repartidos en cuatro formaciones. Ni rastro de una estructura.

> El problema es que solo trabaja con coordenadas enteras y fallan los resultados un poco.

Eso no es un problema, eso es exáctamente como lo has definido. Si el problema es la definición, cambia la definición. También has olvidado describir cuál es el fallo en los resultados, no se puede "*fallar un poco*": o se falla o no se falla ¿Cuál es el fallo? No lo has descrito.

> Necesito buscar los cubos usando coordenadas decimales.

No describes en qué consiste "buscar un cubo", pero si atendemos a tus preguntas anteriores:

- [crear red de cubos usando los espacios de memoria de matrices](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/328960/crear-red-de-cubos-usando-los-espacios-de-memoria-de-matrices).
- [Corregir código en C++](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/331939/corregir-c%c3%b3digo-en-c).
- [C++ Red de cubos mediante vectores](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/333278/c-red-de-cubos-mediante-vectores).

Deducimos<sup>1</sup> que quieres ordenar los cubos en el espacio tridimensional, asignándoles un índice y quieres deducir coordenadas del cubo a través de los índices del mismo.

Así que por enésima vez, [comparto de nuevo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/333672/2742), una vez más, de forma reiterada, con insistencia y repetición las funciones que transforman índices en coordenadas y coordenadas en índices:

```
struct punto { unsigned x{}, y{}, z{}; };

template <unsigned ALTO, unsigned ANCHO, unsigned LARGO>
punto indice_a_coordenada(unsigned indice)
{
    unsigned x = indice % ANCHO;
    unsigned y = indice / (ANCHO * ALTO);
    unsigned z = (indice / ANCHO) % ALTO;
    return {x, y, z};
}

template <unsigned ALTO, unsigned ANCHO, unsigned LARGO>
unsigned coordenada_a_indice(const punto &coordenada)
{
    return {(ANCHO * coordenada.z) + (ANCHO * ALTO * coordenada.y) + coordenada.x};
}
```

Se puede usar en tu función `buscarCubo` de la siguiente manera:

```
unsigned buscarCubo(float x, float y, float z) {
    return coordenada_a_indice<1000, 1000, 1000>({unsigned(x), unsigned(y), unsigned(z)});
}
```

Habrás observado que tu función de 12 líneas queda en una sola línea, te explico los cambios:

1. El retorno pasa a ser un entero sin signo, porque no tendremos jamás índices negativos.
2. Se pasan tres parámetros a la función ya que las coordenadas son sólo tres y el resultado es devuelto por la función, así que tu cuarta formación carecía de sentido.
3. No pido datos en la función, porque los datos son proveídos por los parámetros.
4. Construyo un objeto `punto` para pasar a la función `coordenada_a_indice`, ya que es lo que esta función espera recibir.

   1. Los componentes del objeto `punto` son también enteros sin signo (no esperamos coordenadas negativas), por eso transformamos los `float` en `unsigned`, esto nos trunca la parte decimal.
5. En la llamada a la función `coordenada_a_indice` se indica mediante argumentos de plantilla que la colección de cubos se distribuye en mil cubos en cada eje.

Con estos cambios, tu programa podría quedar así:

```
int main() {
    using namespace std; // Using a nivel local, mejor que a nivel global.

    // Una sola llamada a cout, mejor que varias.
    // Los literales de cadena anexos se concatenan al compilar.
    cout << "\n\tPrograma que simula una geometria construida por cubos,"
            "\n\tcada uno de los cuales esta ubicado por sus coordenadas (x,y,z)"
            "\n\n\t";

    system("PAUSE");

    cout << "\n\n\tBusca un cubo:" << endl;
    float x, y, z;
    cout << "\n\tIngresa la coordenada x: ", cin >> x; 
    cout << "\n\tIngresa la coordenada y: ", cin >> y; 
    cout << "\n\tIngresa la coordenada z: ", cin >> z; 

    cout << "\n\n\tEn esas coordenadas esta el cubo #: " << buscarCubo(x, y, z) << ".\n" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup>Aunque ya no se que pensar, tras preguntar lo mismo cuatro veces ya no se si he entendido tu pregunta.

Comment: muchas gracias!!

Comment: Por favor dime cómo añado esas plantillas a mi código para usarlas como las usas tu en el código que tan elegantemente escribiste, porque mi nivel es tan básico que no puedo hacerlo yo

Comment: Para añadir las funciones plantilla a tu código, basta con 1) copiar 2) pegar.

Comment: Eso de copiar y pegar solo así me da errores,as ayuda ya no se puede?

Comment: Copiar y pegar es imposible que de errores. Podría ser que tuvieras errores al compilar. Ten en cuenta que las funciones deberían estar visibles para el resto del código.

Answer (score 2):

**1. Los indices empiezan en 0 - SIEMPRE**

Da igual que a ti te parezca más cómodo... en C++ los índices empiezan siempre por 0 y es preferible que tu te adaptes a ello a que el código se adapte a ti.

¿Por qué?

Muy sencillo, porque todas las librerías que tengas que usar asumirán que los objetos empiezan en el índice 0. Es decir, tu código será incompatible con librerías de terceros y funcioes hechas por otros compañeros.

Eso por no hablar del desperdicio de memoria que supone tener un elemento *muerto* en cada array que declares.

Además fíjate que tu mismo metes la pata al usar los índices:

```
int Mx[1], My[1], Mz[1];

Mx[1] = i; // Mx[1] no existe!!!
My[1] = j; // Ny[1] no existe!!!
Mz[1] = k; // Mz[1] no existe!!!
```

**2. Cuidado con las variables declaradas varias veces**

```
float x=0.0, y=0.0, z=0.0;
int Xmax, Xmin, i;

cout << "\n\tIngresa la coordenada x: ", cin >> x; 
cout << "\n\tIngresa la coordenada y: ", cin >> y; 
cout << "\n\tIngresa la coordenada z: ", cin >> z; 

for(int i=1; i<=1000; i++){
  if(x >= i && x < i+1){  
   if(y >= i && y < i+1){
     if(z >= i && z < i+1){
```

Si revisas este código con cuidado verás que `i` está declarada dos veces... procura que eso no pase ya que te vas a encontrar con errores difíciles de localizar.

**3. No compares churras con merinas**

```
float x=0.0, y=0.0, z=0.0;

for(int i=1; i<=1000; i++){
  if(x >= i && x < i+1){  
   if(y >= i && y < i+1){
     if(z >= i && z < i+1){
```

En este fragmento estás comparando `i`, que es un índice, con `x`, `y`, `z` que son coordenadas... cualquier comportamiento que se parezca mínimamente al esperado es azar puro y duro... lo que tienes que hacer es comparar coordenadas con coordenadas... ¿y dónde están las coordenadas? en `c1`, `c2`, `c3` y `c4`... que ya me contarás por qué prefieres tener 4 arrays independientes pudiendo usar estructuras:

```
struct Coordenada
{
  float x, y, z;
};

Coordenada cubos[1000];
```

El caso es que hay que comparar coordenadas con coordenadas... y resulta que el tipo usado para las coordenadas es un número decimal. Pues bien, los números decimales tienen una particularidad importante y es **que no son exactos**. Esto sucede así porque hay infinidad de números decimales que no pueden expresarse correctamente usando una representación binaria. Así pues, los números decimales tienen cierta cantidad de *basura*. En el caso de `float`, se considera que los primeros 6 dígitos son los únicos válidos, considerando el resto como *basura*.

¿Por qué te cuento todo esto?

Porque **<s>no puedes</s> no debes** comparar dos números decimales usando los operadores de comparación... al menos no directamente.

Dos números decimales se considerarán equivalentes si ambos se encuentran lo suficientemente cerca el uno del otro. ¿Cómo de cerca? Pues depende de tus requisitos, pero por ejemplo usando `float` y trabajando con coordenadas locales (es decir, números cercanos a 0) podrías entender que dos números son equivalentes si su distancia es inferior a 1e-5.

Con esto en mente las operaciones de comparación serían:

```
bool equal(float a, float b)
{
  float diff = std::abs(a - b);
  return diff < 1e-5;
}

bool greater(float a, float b)
{
  float diff = a-b;
  return diff > 1e-5;
}

bool greaterOrEqual(float a, float b)
{
  float diff = std::abs(a-b);
  return (a>b) || (diff < 1e-5);
}
```

Es decir, no se pueden usar los operadores directamente sino que hay que añadir un intervalo de incertidumbre.

Vale, con esto ya sabemos comparar números decimales... volvamos al tema de comparar coordenadas. Como hemos dicho tenemos que comparar coordenadas con coordenadas:

```
for(int i=0; i<1000; i++)
{
  if( equal(x, c1[i]) && equal(y, c2[i]) && equal(z, c3[i]) )
  { 
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tus respuestas tan bien curradas.

Comment: Sí, muchas gracias!!

Comment: Pero no logro implementarlo :(

Comment: @juan recuerda que siempre puedes publicar una nueva pregunta con tus dudas