# ¿Cómo trabajar con estructuras en C++?

Tags: c++, bucle-for, struct

Este código usa el espacio de memoria de matrices para almacenar 4 números que representan coordenadas de un punto asociado a un vértice de algún cubo **(x, y, z)** y **número de cubo**, ¿Cómo puedo hacer esto usando estructuras?

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int coord1[1001], coord2[1001], coord3[1001], cubo[1001], w, a, b, c, i, j, k, f, t, n=10, etiqueta=0;
    float x=0, y=0, z=0;

    for (i=1; i<=n; i++){
        for (j=1; j<=n; j++){
            for (k=1; k<=n; k++){
                etiqueta++;                         
                coord1[etiqueta]=i;
                coord2[etiqueta]=j;
                coord3[etiqueta]=k;
                cubo[etiqueta]=etiqueta;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "\n\n\tIngresa la coordenada x ", cin >> x;
    cout << "\n\n\tIngresa la coordenada y ", cin >> y;
    cout << "\n\n\tIngresa la coordenada z ", cin >> z;

    a=int(ceil (x)), b=int(ceil (y)),   c=int(ceil (z));

    for(w=0; w<1000; w++){
        if(coord1[w]==a && coord2[w]==b && coord3[w]==c ){
            cout << "\n\tEn esas coordenadas esta en cubo #" << cubo[w] << endl;
        }}

    cout << "\n\n\tIngresa el numero de cubo ", cin >> t;

    for(f=1; f<=1000; f++){
        if(cubo[f]==t){
            cout << "\n\n\tEl cubo #" << t << " esta en las coordenadas: (" << coord1[f] << ", " << coord2[f] << ", " << coord3[f] << ")\n" << endl;
        }}

return 0;
}
```

Para crear una estructura debo definirla y llamarla en cada paso i,j,k para guardar coordenada x=i, y=j, z=k, el número de cada cubo es el contador del número de paso, haciendo:

```
struct cubos
{
    float x, y, z;
    int id;
}cubo;

int main()
{   
    int Xmax, Xmin, Ymax, Ymin, Zmax, Zmin, a, b, c, w, t, f, id = 1, n=10;
    float x, y, z;

    for (int i=1.0; i<=n; i++){
        for (int j=1.0; j<=n; j++){
            for (int k=1.0; k<=n; k++){

                struct cubos cubo;

                cubo.id = id++;
                cubo.x = i;
                cubo.y = j;
                cubo.z = k;
            }
        }
    }
```

Una vez definida la estructura, **¿cómo puedo buscar un cubo por sus coordenadas y viceversa?** empleando números decimales a la hora de buscar por coordenadas.

Comment: **No** puedes definir un cubo con 3 coordenadas. Eso es **un punto**. Un cubo necesita como mínimo 4 datos para definirlo. Por favor, define claramente cual es el problema y su contexto.

Comment: Se te ha respondido a la **misma** pregunta **media docena de veces**.

Comment: si, y muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero cambiaré un poco el código principal para en base a este, hacer un equivalente usando estructuras.

```
int main()
{
    //no es necesario crear una formación de 1001 elementos si solo vamos a usar 1000
    int coord1[1000], coord2[1000], coord3[1000], cubo[1000], w, a, b, c, i, j, k,
        f, t, n = 10, etiqueta = 0;
    float x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            for (k = 0; k < n; ++k) {
                //en C++ la indexación es basada en cero, se debe rellenar apartir de esa ubicación
                coord1[etiqueta] = i + 1;
                coord2[etiqueta] = j + 1;
                coord3[etiqueta] = k + 1;
                cubo[etiqueta] = etiqueta + 1;
                ++etiqueta;
            }
        }
    }

    std::cout << "\n\n\tIngresa la coordenada x ", std::cin >> x;
    std::cout << "\n\n\tIngresa la coordenada y ", std::cin >> y;
    std::cout << "\n\n\tIngresa la coordenada z ", std::cin >> z;

    a = int(ceil(x)), b = int(ceil(y)), c = int(ceil(z));

    for (w = 0; w < 1000; ++w) {
        if (coord1[w] == a && coord2[w] == b && coord3[w] == c) {
            std::cout << "\n\tEn esas coordenadas esta en cubo #" << cubo[w] <<
                std::endl;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "\n\n\tIngresa el numero de cubo ", std::cin >> t;

    for (f = 0; f < 1000; ++f) {
        if (cubo[f] == t) {
            std::cout << "\n\n\tEl cubo #" << t << " esta en las coordenadas: (" 
                << coord1[f] << ", " << coord2[f] << ", " << coord3[f] << ")\n" <<
                std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

El equivalente usando la estructura:

```
struct cubos
{
    int x, y, z, id;
};
```

sería:

```
int main()
{
    int a, b, c, w, t, f, n = 10,etiqueta=0;
    float x, y, z;
    cubos miscubos[1000];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            for (int k = 0; k < n; ++k) {
                miscubos[etiqueta].id= etiqueta + 1;
                miscubos[etiqueta].x = i+1;
                miscubos[etiqueta].y = j+1;
                miscubos[etiqueta].z = k+1;
                ++etiqueta;
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout << "\n\n\tIngresa la coordenada x ", std::cin >> x;
    std::cout << "\n\n\tIngresa la coordenada y ", std::cin >> y;
    std::cout << "\n\n\tIngresa la coordenada z ", std::cin >> z;

    a = int(ceil(x)), b = int(ceil(y)), c = int(ceil(z));

    for (w = 0; w < 1000; ++w) {
        if (miscubos[w].x == a && miscubos[w].y == b && miscubos[w].z == c) {
            std::cout << "\n\tEn esas coordenadas esta en cubo #" <<
                miscubos[w].id << std::endl;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "\n\n\tIngresa el numero de cubo ", std::cin >> t;

    for (f = 0; f < 1000; ++f) {
        if (miscubos[f].id == t) {
            std::cout << "\n\n\tEl cubo #" << t << " esta en las coordenadas: (" 
                << miscubos[f].x << ", "<< miscubos[f].y << ", " <<
                miscubos[f].z << ")\n" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

En este punto tengo que preguntar ¿es necesario almacenar todas las coordenadas y etiquetas?, [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/335875/154404) tienes una respuesta a una pregunta tuya, que aceptaste como correcta, en dónde se usa estructuras, creo que es una alternativa bastante buena para pasar de coordenadas a etiquetas y viceversa si es que no necesitas almacenar las coordenadas o etiquetas, creo que las etiquetas no son las mismas que generan los códigos anteriores, pero podrían adaptarse, o tal vez podrías tu adaptarte a ellas.